# Как проверить правильность введенных данных в ячейку во время игры в крестики нолики?

Tags: java

Как проверить правильность введенных данных в ячейку во время игры в крестики нолики?
Нужно считать правильным вводом, если на одной строке ввели два числа (столбец и строку) от 1 до 3. Пробелов может быть сколько угодно.

Нужно написать функцию, которая принимает строку и возвращает клетку Cell в случае, если строка содержит только пробелы и два числа от 1 до 3. Иначе функция должна вернуть null.
Классы
Имя класса: Cell, поля: int row, int col.

Сигнатура функции
Название функции: parseMove.

Параметры: String line.

Возвращаемый тип: Cell.

Ниже код моего решения, но он выводит только числовой массив. Дальше как я понимаю мне нужно циклом пройтись по этому массиву и проверить их. Я это вроде бы делаю, но программа все ровно выводит тот массив, хотя если я ввожу в  main не числовые значения, то получаю ошибку.
Мой вопрос: как решить задачу, чтобы правильно проверять введенные данные.

```
public class TicTacToe_105 {
    public static class Cell{
        public int row;
        public int col;

        public Cell(){
        }
        public Cell(int row, int col){
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
        }
    }
    public static Cell parseMove(String line) {
        Cell num = new Cell();
        String str [] = line.split(" ", 1);
        int array [] = new int[str.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
            if (array[i] >= 1 && array[i] <= 3){
                num.equals(array);
            }else{
                num = null;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "13454";
        parseMove(line);
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: 0. Вам нужно взять два полученных числа и присвоить их полям row и cell клетки num. 1. Прочитайте текст ошибки. Там будет написано, почему она возникает. 2. Прочитайте в учебнике про исключения и их обработку (try..catch). 3. Этих знаний будет достаточно, чтобы решить проблему.

Comment: что вы хотите сделать в строке ``num.equals(array);``?

Comment: Так вы и выводите `System.out.println(line);`, а не результаты функции

Comment: `line.split(" ", 1);` вернёт только одну цифру, если они введены через пробел.

Comment: у мня получилось одно число, а не два. А если я введу не число а другие символы или буквы, тогда метод парсинга не подходит вообще. И что тогда мне использовать для преобразования

Comment: *А если я введу не число а другие символы или буквы* - тогда вылетит исключение на `array[i] = Integer.parseInt`. Используйте `preg_replace` чтобы отфильтровать только цифры.

Comment: line.split(" ", 1); вернёт только одну цифру, если они введены через пробел. т.е здесь я должна прописать: вот так : line.split(" ", 2)?

Comment: Вот этой записью я хочу присвоить клетке  num  все числовые значения массива чисел - ил это вообще не нужно...? Но мне не понятно как иначе присвоить значения  row  и  col

Comment: Присвоить полученному числу значения вот так:  array[i] = num.row;
            array[i] = num.col; ?

Comment: 0. Вам нужно взять два полученных числа и присвоить их полям row и cell клетки num.  В моем решении у меня есть только 1 полученное число. Это  array[i] -  когда я пишу:  num.row = array[i]; num.col = array[i]; то оба значения присваиваются одному числу, Т. е если на входе 1 3 - то на выходе получается  1 1, Что мне делать?

Comment: выше я добавила измененную функцию...

Comment: Вы код наугад пишете? Вы присваиваете одно число, неудивительно, что в итоге присваивается одно число. Если в вопрос добавили измененную функцию, то удалите все остальное, что не относится к проблеме и в самом вопросе укажите, какая именно проблема. В комментариях сложно выискивать.

Comment: и вообще, делайте задание по порядку. Начните, например, с реализации этого требования: "если строка содержит только пробелы и два числа от 1 до 3". У вас уже здесь неправильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Cell parseMove(String line) {
    Cell num = new Cell();
    // удаляем пробелы в начале и конце строки и множественные пробелы
    line = line.replaceAll("[\\s]{2,}", " ").trim();
    // проверяем наличие посторонних символов
    String str = line.replaceAll("[^ 1-3]", "");
    // в итоге должны остаться две цифры и один пробел мужду ними
    if (str.length() != 3 || !str.equals(line))
        return null;
    str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
    int tmp = Integer.parseInt(str);
    num.row = tmp / 10;
    num.col = tmp % 10;
    return num;
}
```

Comment: это решение другой задачи, а не той, которая в вопросе. По условию, если я введу, скажем, "13" или "22" или "43 25", то нужно вернуть null.

Comment: @Эникейщик, `Нужно считать правильным вводом, если на одной строке ввели два числа (столбец и строку) от 1 до 3`. Про пробелы **между** ними ничего не сказано. Про "43 25" - согласен, недоработка.

Comment: два числа подразумевают как минимум один пробел между ними

Comment: Спасибо за вариант решения , хочу уточнить, что  про пробелы сказано в условии: "функцию, которая принимает строку и возвращает клетку Cell в случае, если строка содержит только пробелы и два числа от 1 до 3." l

Comment: Последний вариант кода к сожалению  тоже выдает ошибку. Ошибка в том, что если line = "3 -5        1"; - то должен быть result = null;l, а получается результат result = {
  "col" : 1,
  "row" : 3
};

Comment: @Эникейщик, поправил. Но про пробелы между - не согласен.

Comment: вы тоже из тех, кто путает числа и цифры? 13 - это одно число. Тринадцать. Но две цифры. Один и три. "1 3" - два числа и две цифры. Один и три.

Comment: А, ну да. Главное, чтоб код работал )

Comment: ну вот по последнему варианту кода сейчас такая ошибка: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 3"

Comment: Что это значит?

Comment: Ошибка: Входные данные:
line = "22";
Ожидаемый результат:
result = null;
Результат вашего решения:
result = {
  "col" : 2,
  "row" : 2
};

Comment: Получается нужен пробел между значениями как условие.

Comment: Почему вот эта строка не добавляет пробелы между числами? : String str2 = line.replaceAll("[^1-3]", " ");  Кто может подсказать как правильно решить эту задачу?

Comment: @ЕкатеринаШирвель, доработал. Просто изначально про пробелы между символами условия не было.

Comment: Спасибо сейчас буду разбираться)))  проверю на платформе, куда сдаю задачу - обязательно отпишусь )))

Comment: Работает!! - огромное спасибо...!